# PlayFramework not able to run of VPS server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, playframework, vps

I have a xen-vps server and I was trying to run play-framework application in it.

But as soon as I set the PATH env. variable

export PATH=$PATH:/path_to_play/

and try to create a new play application, it gives "illegal instruction"

Please refer the screenshot :

[image]

Comment: type `uname -a`. what is the output?

Comment: my OS is ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit arch.

Comment: I am sure you tried this already, but in case you didnt, if you go into your play_home directory and type play run do you still get the same error?

Comment: @JohnKane yes I tried that, it still gives the same error. it is not able to run the play script even from the home folder.

Comment: Too bad that would have been simple. Maybe they require a different version of python than you have installed?

Comment: @rao_555 i guess you should just run  `uname -a` and  see

Comment: @J-16SDiZ, the output of uname -a is :    Linux rhino.fadfish.com 3.2.0-24-virtual #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 18:44:18 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: it looks like they require at least python 2.5. They also require at least java 5, but I dont think you are getting to that point.

Comment: @JohnKane, i am having python2.7 and open-jdk-7

Comment: ok I only brought up the java version because it looked like you were putting it on the classpath of a 1.4 sdk

Comment: do any of the play commands work?

Comment: @JohnKane, the 1.4 sdk shown in the PATH is not java 1.4 sdk, it is app-engine-1.4 sdk.

Comment: @JohnKane none of the play commands are working. It is not able to run the play script

Comment: Maybe a chmod +x would solve it !?

Comment: was this resolved?  just curious (did you reboot the VM after making the changes for play)

Comment: @alihaider, No the issue still exist, even after rebooting the VM, Play framework somehow does not run on the VPS server.

Comment: @alihaider, I tried to get this issue resolved from the cq5 forums and irc too, but seems nobody else faced this issue. Are you facing the similar problem?

Comment: I am able to run play (v1.2.3) fine at Amazon AWS.  I had to add the path to Play, ensure that I had JDK 6/7 setup, I rebooted the VM and was able to run play commands (e.g. play run, play start, play install etc.).  Can you share your current path (echo $PATH) - if the path does not contain a reference to the play framework, that is the issue